# Early access to configuration

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, typesafe-config

Is there any way to get early access to configuration (before com.typesafe.config.Config.resolve() would be called)? I would like to provide custom behavior when unresolved substitutions are encountered
during resolution ([link to feature in typesafe config](https://lightbend.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/ConfigResolver.html))

I am using Play 2.6.x

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no place in Play to access configuration that early. The configuration is loaded by `DevServerStart`/`ProdServerStart` using hard coded loading logic and passed to the `ServerProvider` and the `ApplicationLoader`.

The `ApplicationLoader` ([Java](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaCompileTimeDependencyInjection#Application-entry-point), [Scala](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaCompileTimeDependencyInjection#Application-entry-point)) does have the ability to *rewrite* configuration if that works for you.

We could add support for a custom `ConfigResolver` as a new feature in Play. It would probably have to be driven from a system property to find the correct class. If you'd like this feature, please [create an issue](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/new).

Comment: Thanks, _rewrite_ would not help in my case. Have made an [issue](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/8116)

Comment: Thanks! [Link](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/8116)